# JOOQ Debug Log not working

Tags: java, slf4j, jooq

I am using jOOQ with slf4j, and set log level to DEBUG. In my class when i check the log level
its in debug mood

```
System.out.println(LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonsReport.class).isDebugEnabled()); => true
```

But same class i am running some select queries using JOOQ ,but JOOQ debug log is not printing  in my log, What can be the reason ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue , but i was surprised by the solution, I put 'getResult()' at the end of the JOOQ query the result set is null and JOOQ debug log also not printing, but when i change it to 'fetch()' then result set is not null and JOOQ log also printed

I don't know what is the behind thing for this, but issue was fixed

Thanks

Comment: This is explained in the [`fetch()` Javadoc](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetch()). [`getResult()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#getResult()) returns *"the result generated by a previous call to execute();"*